# How can I encode a Perl string so I can put it into an XML document?

Tags: xml, perl, encoding, character-encoding

I'm not too fluent with the perl XML libraries (actually, I really suck at understanding encoding in general), all I'm doing is taking a string that possibly has characters such as "à" and putting it in an XML file, but when I open the file, I get an encoding error at the line containing such a character.

So I just need a lightweight way to take a string and encode it for XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML should specify UTF-8 encoding. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

There's a lot of good information at [UTF-8 and Unicode Standards](http://www.utf8.com/).

Your Perl program should also be set its output filehandle to the UTF-8 encoding so it writes the data correctly. See the perl documentation for [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), for instance.

The only XML-specific escaping you need is for the XML reserved characters. See [Where can I get a list of the XML document escape characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/xml-escape-characters) on Stackoverflow.

You can use Perl's [XML::Code](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Code) or a similar module to escape the XML-specific chars

Comment: Answer could be a lot better: ① Sloppy hypertext copy (use of "here", anaemic link texts). ② Potentially confusing information: `use utf8;` is in fact only necessary to tell Perl that the programmer has encoded the Perl source code in UTF-8. This is a different concept than writing files with an encoding which was asked in the question. ③ Inaccurate terminology: Escaping is needed for *delimiters* (XML §4.6). ④ Lack of permalink to the module.

Comment: I've fixed all of that. I think you missed the biggest problem: you shouldn't be writing out XML by hand, so you should never have to even think about this. Use a module that does it all for you. :) Oh, and get a little more rep and you can fix things too :)

Answer (score 4):

Example using [LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/), which is the standard big hammer for XML. Not lightweight, but your problem really is a familiar nail and at least we're not spending much time writing code, either.

```
use XML::LibXML ();
XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8')->createTextNode($text)->toString; # returns properly encoded fragment
```

See method [`toFile`](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Document#toFile) for writing into a file.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get answer 2 to work.  Try this, it produces XML which says "not well-formed (invalid token)":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

use XML::LibXML;
use HTML::Entities;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
my $string = 'foo &auml; bar';
$string = decode_entities($string);
print XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8')->createTextNode($string)->toString();
```